# List of SelectItem List's, How do I set selected in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a create page that lets the user select a shirt from a dropdown, the user also has an option to add another shirt, to do this, the user hits an add button and a new dropdownlist is dynamically created and added to the page below the previous dropdown.

I am trying to populate all the  drop downs, each with the selected shirt, in my edit page. The drop downs are added successfully and populated to the editpage, but I am having trouble setting the selected shirt to what the user selected when they created it.

Currently, I have a List of List's. I loop through a List of shirt names from an order db and set the selected value to each List that has a matching name to true.

I break at just before the model is sent to the view and all is good, the item I expect to be selected is true, however, break at my view, nothing is set to selected.

Here is my Edit function in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var mod = GetOrderInfo(id);

    //Call GetAllShirts, returns a IList<<SelectListItem> and sets the models List<SelectListItem> to that returned value
    mod.ShirtsList = GetAllShirts().ToList();

    List<List<SelectListItem>> shirtLists = new List<List<SelectListItem>>();

    //foreach shirt in mod.shirts, List<string>
    foreach (var shirt in mod.shirts)
    {
        //loop through List and set selected to true if it matches the current index value of the outer loop
        foreach (var item in mod.ShirtsList)
        {
            if (item.Value == shirt)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //add List<selectlistitem> to List
        shirtLists.Add(mod.ShirtsList);
    }

    //Set mods List<List<SelectListItem>> to shirtLists
    mod.shirtLists = shirtLists;

    return View(mod);
}
```

View Part

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.shirtLists.Count; i++)
{
  <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.shirtName,Model.shirtLists[i] )</p>
}
```

Comment: This is a limitation of using `DropDownListFor()` in a loop. Setting the `Selected` of `SelectListItem` is pointless (its ignored when binding to a property in your model). You need to show your model and the `GetAllShirts()` method in order to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need unique lists for each drop down. The following will work just fine:

```
  <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Shirts[0].shirtName, Model.shirtLists)</p>
  ...
  <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Shirts[1].shirtName, Model.shirtLists)</p>
  ...
  etc.
```

Where `Model.shirtLists` is now just `List<SelectListItem>` instead of `List<List<SelectListItem>>`. You don't need to set `Selected` on each `SelectListItem`, either. `Html.DropDownListFor` will automatically render the matching option as selected based on the value of the current `shirtName`.

However, what is likely your problem is that you're binding each drop down to the same property, `Model.shirtName`. That means the last dropdown on the page wins, and whatever it posts will be the value. You need something like the following code, instead:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Shirts.Count; i++)
{
  <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Shirts[i].shirtName, Model.shirtLists)</p>
}
```

Where `Model.Shirts` would be a list of `Shirt` (or whatever class holds `shirtName`) instances.

Comment: Model.shirts is a List<string>, like it only contains shirt1, shirt2. When I just do <p>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Shirts[i], Model.shirtLists)</p>, it still doesnt have the names selected.